# How to condense column data in excel at a change in the row data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure exactly how to explain this, but I want to combine rows in Excel while condensing the column data. I'm looking to take a spreadsheet like this:

| Name | Coffee | Bananas | Chocolate Ice Cream |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 4 |  |  |
| Tom |  | 2 |  |
| Tom |  |  | 2 |
| Jerry | 1 |  |  |
| Jerry |  |  | 4 |
| Amanda |  | 3 |  |
| Amanda |  |  | 2 |

and turn it into this:

| Name | Coffee | Bananas | Chocolate Ice Cream |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| Jerry | 1 |  | 4 |
| Amanda |  | 3 | 2 |

Any tips would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a pivot table for this.

Select your table > Insert Pivot Table, then follow this screenshot:

[image: Pivot Table]

Drag `Name` colum in `Rows`
Drag `Coffee`, `Bananas`, `Chocolate ice creams` in `Values` and you're set!

Comment: thank you so much! this worked beautifully. I totally forgot about a PivotTable

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data transformed and cleansed, you can always use PowerQuery.

Go to `Data` -> `Get Data` -> `From File` -> whatever source your data is in.

In there, use the `Group By` function to suppress the rows.

[image: Group By]

From there, you'll have a new set of data which can then be loaded into the destination worksheet.

[image: Result]

If the usage of PowerQuery is new to you, a quick Google search will help you through this.

Naturally, this assumes you have a version of Excel that has PQ built in.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gYsjeHjKcnUochws5w?e=ED3Ojg)/screenshot(s) refer:

*Condensed* table comprises 3 sections (colour coded respectively):

1. Row labels (names, blue) - assuming these are unique at source
2. Column labels (food product, green) - ditto
3. Values (sum per row / col label, yellow)

*note: included an extra '1' for Tom + Chocolate IC in 1st row for testing...*

**1] Row labels**

```
=UNIQUE(D7:D13)
```

[image: Unique row labels]

*(array function - requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel)*

---

**2] Col labels**

```
=E6:G6
```

[image: Col labels]

*(array function - enter in single cell if using Office 365 compatible version of Excel, otherwise highlight relevant area and enter function with `shift + alt + enter`)*

---

**3] Values**

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($E$7:$G$13,0,MATCH(J$6,$E$6:$G$6,0)),$D$7:$D$13,$I7)
```

[image: Values]

*(can drag this function across values / yellow section)*

---